# How to export ESRI Geodatabase format .gdb from PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, file-geodatabase

I found several posts explaining how to import a .gdb file into PostGIS.
Is exporting also possible?
For example using `ogr2ogr` to generate a .gdb file from query result.

Comment: Biggest problem is probably with building GDAL with ESRI FileGDB SDK https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/FileGDB. Once you have the driver it should be just `ogr2ogr -f FileGDB -sql "select * from my_data" output.gdb PG:...`

Answer (score 2):

Yes its possible using the ogr2ogr package with gdal.

```
sudo apt-get -y install gdal-bin
```

`ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=localhost port=5432 dbname=osm user=postgres password=123" something.gdb -overwrite -progress --config PG_USE_COPY YES`